# How to decode and encode the h264 live streaming data in ios using ffmpeg?

Tags: ios, iphone, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

How to decode and encode the h264 live streaming data in **ios** using **ffmpeg** with a **example**?

Answer (score 1):

This is quoted from the link below:

> How to use FFmpeg in iOS. To use FFmpeg in your xCode project you must follow below steps:
>
> 1- Build FFmpeg library for iOS
>
> 2- Integrate library & headers in your project
>
> 3- Write Decoder class for RTSP URL
>
> 4- Display decoded frames on iOS device

Q/A   [Building ffmpeg iOS libraries for armv7, armv7s, arm64, i386 and universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789827/building-ffmpeg-ios-libraries-for-armv7-armv7s-arm64-i386-and-universal)

Also check this [RTSP/RTMP Video Streaming Client iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20962029/rtsp-rtmp-video-streaming-client-ios)

Comment: http://ffmpegwithios.blogspot.com/2014/03/real-time-streaming-in-ios-using-ffmpeg.html link died

Comment: Thanks. I tried to find an alternative but with no success so I removed it.

Answer (score -1):

Go through This link. 
Here he get iphone the camera feed and encode it into h264 format and send it to server.

http://www.wenda.io/questions/723366/can-ffmpeg-library-send-the-live-h264-ios-camera-stream-to-wowza-using-rtsp.html

Comment: it is a bad idea to leave only link as answer, as in future, they might stop working.

Comment: omi can you explain detail please?

Comment: i have to decode the byte array data which is in .h264 format?